# Pure JavaScript Slideshow Play/Pause with Spacebar

Tags: javascript, events, slideshow, break, pause

I'm trying to make a JavaScript slideshow ([here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o12dbh4y/)) with automatically-playing audio for each slide with the functionality to allow right arrow (for next slide), left arrow (for previous slide), or space bar to play from the current slide to the last slide, with space bar also being used to pause the slideshow (and then again to resume, etc.).

The only problem I am experiencing is with getting the space bar to pause the slideshow. For debugging, I'm logging to the console when it is suppose to pause, and it seems to be executing this functionality the number of times as the slide number, albeit without actually pausing the slideshow--e.g. if I push space bar when on slide 2, it executes twice, but if I push space bar yet again when it reaches slide 4, it executes 6 times (2+4), etc.

I have tried the following code most recently to no avail:

```
(function loop(){
        var breakout;
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(secondkey) {if (secondkey.keyCode == 32){breakout = "1"; console.log("paused on slide #" + slidenumber + "!");}})
        if (slidenumber >= slidelength || breakout == "1") return;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (breakout == "1") return;
            console.log("slide #: " + slidenumber);
            showDivs(slidenumber += 1);
            loop();
        }, 1000);
    })();
```

I've also tried this failing code:

```
(function loop() {
        var breakout;
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(secondkey) {if (secondkey.keyCode == 32){breakout = "1"; console.log("paused on slide #" + slidenumber + "!");}})
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (slidenumber >= slidelength || breakout == "1") {console.log("breakout on slide #" + slidenumber + "!"); return;}
            else {
                console.log("slide ##: " + slidenumber);
                showDivs(slidenumber += 1);
                loop();
            }
        },1000);
    })();
```

...and this failing code:

```
for (a = slidenumber; a < slidelength; a++) {
            var breakout;
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(secondkey) {if (secondkey.keyCode == 32){breakout = "1"; console.log("paused!");}})
            if (breakout == "1"){break;}
            (function(ind) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    showDivs(slidenumber += 1);
                }, 2 * 1000 * ind); // Change slide every 2 seconds
            })(a);
        }
```

And even this failing code:

```
var func = function(slidenumber){
        return function(){
            if (slidenumber >= slidelength) return;
            console.log("turn no. " + slidenumber);
            showDivs(slidenumber += 1);

            var breakout;
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(secondkey) {if (secondkey.keyCode == 32){breakout = "1"; console.log("paused!");}})
            if(breakout == "1") {
                console.log('slideshow paused');
            } else {
                setTimeout(func(++slidenumber), 2000);
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(func(0), 2000);
```

What can I do to get this to work? My entire code is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Slideshow</title>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="slide-content">
        <img style="height:80vh;" onclick="play(1)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
        <audio id="audio-1" src="https://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2218&type=mp3"></audio>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-content">
        <img style="height:80vh;" onclick="play(2)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546521343-4eb2c01aa44b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
        <audio id="audio-2" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2212&type=mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-content">
        <img style="height:80vh;" onclick="play(3)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543002588-bfa74002ed7e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
        <audio id="audio-3" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2210&type=mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-content">
        <img style="height:80vh;" onclick="play(4)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507842217343-583bb7270b66?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Nnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
        <audio id="audio-4" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2204&type=mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide-content">
        <img style="height:80vh;" onclick="play(5)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532012197267-da84d127e765?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8NHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
        <audio id="audio-5" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2184&type=mp3"></audio>
    </div>

    <div onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Previous</div>
    <div onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next</div>

    <script>
    var slidelength = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-content").length;
    
    function play(nr) {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-"+nr); audio.play(); 
    }

    var slidenumber = 1;
    showDivs(slidenumber);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slidenumber += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-content");
        if (n > slidelength) {slidenumber = n-1} // Do not loop
        if (n < 1) {slidenumber = n+1} // If left is pushed on first slide, stay on first slide
        for (i = 0; i < slidelength; i++) {
            slide[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slide[slidenumber-1].style.display = "block";
        console.log("# of slides: " + slidelength);
        console.log("slide #: " + slidenumber);
        play(slidenumber);
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(pronounce) {
        if (pronounce.keyCode == 39) {showDivs(slidenumber += 1);} // Right Arrow
        if (pronounce.keyCode == 37) {showDivs(slidenumber -= 1);} // Left Arrow

        // Space bar, when pushed, should loop through automatically until last slide. if space bar is pushed again pause. if pushed yet again continue. etc.
        if (pronounce.keyCode == 32) { // Space Bar

        // Working, but not the pause
        (function loop(){
            var breakout;
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(secondkey) {if (secondkey.keyCode == 32){breakout = "1"; console.log("paused on slide #" + slidenumber + "!");}})
            if (slidenumber >= slidelength || breakout == "1") return;
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (breakout == "1") return;
                console.log("slide #: " + slidenumber);
                showDivs(slidenumber += 1);
                loop();
            }, 1000);
        })();
        }
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimum reproducable example? If you make a snippet, it will be easier for people to try out their answers.

Comment: @programmerRaj, thanks! I added [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o12dbh4y/) to the beginning of the question.